# In PowerShell, how do I set $HOME variable before running a script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to Windows PowerShell. Basically, before running a script in command line, I would like to set the $HOME environment variable to a different directory.

I don't really want to change the system $HOME variable that may affect other software. I just want this change to affect the script I am running  or just the shell I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend changing $HOME but if you must:

```
Set-Variable -Name Home -Value C:\Windows -Force
```

This will impact the shell/session and every script that runs in this shell.  If doing this for a script you might think about setting it back after the script finishes e.g.:

```
$oldHome = $Home
Set-Variable -Name Home -Value C:\windows -Force
...
Set-Variable -Name Home -Value $oldHome -Force
```

Comment: User defined variables will do a "copy-on-write" in lower scopes.  However `$Home` is a `built-in`, automatic variable that is marked ReadOnly so it behaves a bit differently.